# Подмена двузначных чисел

Tags: javascript, jquery, алгоритм

Есть вот такой алгоритм, который подменяет цифры:

```
if ($('.ellipsis:contains("256")').length) {
    if ($('.ellipsis:contains("256")').text()=='256'){
        $('.ellipsis:contains("256")').text('112');
    }
}
```

Всё работает хорошо, но с двузначными числам отказывается работать, вот пример именно с двузначными:

```
if ($('.ellipsis:contains("30")').length) {
    if ($('.ellipsis:contains("30")').text()=='30'){
        $('.ellipsis:contains("30")').text('168');
    }
}
```

Прошу объяснить максимально человеческим языком, что не так, ну или что ещё надо "запихнуть" в код, чтобы эта шайтан-машина заработала.

Заранее спасибо!

Comment: А там у вас пробел в начале завалялся за место третьей цифры.

Comment: Извините, но не понимаю, где пробел, минут 15 сидел и думал, где пробел, может быть я его не вижу. 
Могу попросить просто изменить и прикрепить в комментарий алгоритм?

Comment: Мы вынуждены гадать - Вы вставили в вопрос код, но не вставили данные, с которыми этому коду приходится работать. Добавьте html, чтобы получился пример, воспроизводящий поведение, которое Вы наблюдаете. Используйте кнопку "Фрагмент кода ..." в редакторе вопроса.

Answer (score 1):

Проверяйте пробелы, иначе не попадете в условие `$('.ellipsis2:contains("30")').text() == '30'`

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  if ($('.ellipsis:contains("256")').length) {
    if ($('.ellipsis:contains("256")').text() == '256') {
      $('.ellipsis:contains("256")').text('112');
    }
  }

  if ($('.ellipsis2:contains("30")').length) {
    if ($('.ellipsis2:contains("30")').text() == '30') {
      $('.ellipsis2:contains("30")').text('168');
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="ellipsis">256</div>
<div class="ellipsis2">30</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

http://api.jquery.com/text/

> Get the combined text contents of each element in the set of matched
>   elements, including their descendants,
>
> Получить объединенное текстовое содержимое  всех выбранных элементов, включая дочерние

Если элементов больше одного или у них есть подэлементы со своим текстом - сравнение вернет `false`.